# What is the ideal composite index for this query?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

What is the ideal *Composite Index* in MySQL for the following query on an InnoDB Table1?

```
SELECT ColA 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ColB = 0 
AND ColC = 0 
AND ColD = 0
```

*ColA* is the left-most Primary Key.

*ColB* has fewer "0" rows than *ColC*, and *ColC* has fewer "0" results than *ColD*.

When using the composite index *(ColB, ColC, ColD)* on the query above, MySQL is instead using an *Intersect* of Indices *ColB*, *ColC*, and *ColD*.

Here is the requested `SHOW CREATE TABLE Table1 ;` results:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
 `ColA` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `ColE` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColF` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColB` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColG` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColC` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColH` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColD` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColJ` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColK` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColM` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ColP` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ColA`),
 KEY `ColB` (`ColB`),
 KEY `ColG` (`ColG`),
 KEY `ColC` (`ColC`),
 KEY `ColH` (`ColH`),
 KEY `ColD` (`ColD`),
 KEY `ColJ` (`ColJ`),
 KEY `ColK` (`ColK`),
 KEY `ColB_2` (`ColB`,`ColC`,`ColD`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(ColB, ColC, ColD)
```

with the columns in *any* order, is good.  This takes care of all of the `WHERE` clause.

Potentially even better is a "covering" index:

```
INDEX(ColB, ColC, ColD, ColA)
```

with `ColA` *last*.

"Covering means that all the columns in the `SELECT` are in the index.  That way, the query can be performed in the BTree for the index, and not have to jump over to the data for anything else.

If the table is InnoDB, then the first index will contain ColA.  This is because any secondary index implicitly contains the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Even in a covering index, the order is important.

Index Merge Intersect is almost never faster than a Composite index that handles the correct columns.  (I think of Index Merge as a clue that you should add a Composite index.)

[More on building optimal indexes.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Do not use `DESC`, it is not as descriptive as `SHOW CREATE TABLE` !

Drop KEY `ColB` (`ColB`) -- it is now redundant.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good key choice.

MySQL is probably using the index_merge optimization to do that intersection:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html

It can be disabled by running:

```
    SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off";
```

More information on this is available:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/14/the-optimization-that-often-isnt-index-merge-intersection/

EDIT:  Wait, do you have any other indexes on this table?  Can you show us an example of:

```
    DESC tablename;
```

Comment: Yes, I have separate indices on each of the individual columns in this InnoDB table.  Instead of MySQL using the Composite Index, it's using the Intersect of the individual indices.  What would you suggest?

Comment: Separate indexes is _not_ as good as a composite index in this case.